# Reputation disparity between commenting and answering

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lower the amount of reputation needed to comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12119/lower-the-amount-of-reputation-needed-to-comment)

I get that this probably isn't an issue for many users since 50 reputation (the current amount required to attain the "Comment everywhere" privilege) isn't much, but...

Posting an answer isn't always the appropriate way to contribute to a topic. Obviously, or the commenting mechanism wouldn't exist. Do I want to ask the poster of a question for clarification? If so, the correct way to do this is to post a comment below the question. Do I wish to expand on or add to another user's existing answer, but without actually adding enough information to be considered a complete alternative answer in its own right? Again, the correct way to do this is to post a comment.

But, I'm unable to do this given my current reputation level (25). In fact, if I *really* have the burning compulsion to post my thoughts, I'd be forced to ignore the above guidelines and provide an "answer" which isn't one. This is actually really annoying, and has happened to me recently several times in the last few months when I've signed in wanting to post a comment, and remembered I couldn't. In the end, I did nothing, and logged out again.

EDIT: my opinion on this matter is that whatever reputation is required to post and required to comment should be the same, or at least the reputation required to comment should be a lot lower, say 10 or 20.

Comment: Answering doesn't require any reputation at all. (Nor does posting a question, for that matter.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lower the amount of reputation needed to comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12119/lower-the-amount-of-reputation-needed-to-comment) You may also be interested in [Make comment privilege more flexible](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157884/make-comment-privilege-more-flexible-configurable)

Comment: woops, yep it's pretty much a duplicate of that one.

"the reputation threshold of comments is forcing people to use the site in ways the designers did not intend" essentially sums up my point, although I would amend it to "... use the site in ways the designers did not intend, or else leave the site dissatisfied".

Comment: You're not referring to yourself with that amended statement, are you...?

Comment: Well yeah, I browse SO, view a thread, want to comment, can't, take no further action, then leave? What else is there to do? Aside from offering my thoughts as an "answer", which they often don't qualify as