# Undo a comment upvote in the Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app

I just accidentally upvoted a comment while browsing SE using the Android app, and wanted to remove that upvote once I had realized my mistake.

However, there is no option to remove the upvote, while it seems  I still get the choice to upvote a comment although I already did that.

I chose upvote again, hoping this would effectively remove my upvote, but in fact it did nothing.

Comment: Perhaps we must sacrifice some functionality to use our wee-little devices

Comment: I'd totally accept that, and I don't consider that a bug, rather a feature request with not-so-high priority. However, if there is a possibility to upvote a comment, there should be one to remove the upvote as well, IMHO.

Comment: Not saying this shouldn't be implemented, but [comments are second class citizens](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). Compared to app crashes and other requested features, this will probably rank low.

Answer (score 2):

While this seems like a "not at all important" feature, it *is* entirely too easy for me and my massive fingers to accidentally upvote a comment when I mean to hit "profile".  And I am more likely to look at a commenter's profile when it's a poor comment and I'm thinking about flagging it. In fact, since upvote is in the middle, I'll bet I hit when I mean to hit flag, too.

I can also see myself thinking I'm upvoting the good comment but actually upvoting the one under it.

It would be nice if either I couldn't upvote comments at all, or could undo that upvote.