# Why do I need at least 50 reputation to post a comment?

Tags: support, comments

I just made an account, so I do not have any reputation yet.
I know the answer on a question in a comment, I would like to post a comment to answer it, but I can't because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Well, you cant. First you should watch the questions alone and try to answer them and get them accepted, so you will reach 50 points.

Comment: @S.L.Barth there's a special faq, pretty new, for exactly those questions.

Comment: @ShadowWizard You mean the Help Center? Can I flag something as a duplicate of a Help Center entry? (Going to try next time!) BTW the [Help Center entry about comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) doesn't explain _why_ 50 rep are required.

Comment: @S.L.Barth no, [this faq question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks, now I understand what you meant.

Answer (score -2):

Did you ever made bad comments or questions? because if so maybe your account is blocked untill you have a good reputation like you said yourself, try to get better reputation and you will be answering questions in no time!

Comment: I think its normal with new accounts. Every new user has to get 50 points to comment questions. Anybody else can comment answers like yours for example.