# Is there a site about medicine, healthcare and illness?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, site-proposal

I can't find, may be this is already exist.

What do you think about such SE?

SE about medicine, about different Illness.

I know that this is bad to healing yourself without real medic.

However, if a medic already complete a diagnose, would be great to get additional information about an illness.

For example, every nation have each own receipts against flu. I know that in Russia it is warming body, but in USA it is cooling. Etc...

Should I go to the Area51 with this question?

Comment: Yes, you should go to Area 51 and create the proposal.

Comment: @ChrisF There is a proposal on [Health](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66048/health) at Area 51

Comment: Just to update info for who comes here from Google, at this moment Health SE is there and is in beta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not a site like this.

However, there may be a proposed site that will possibly cover some types of questions you have in these regards, as posted by [@Benny Skoberg](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239753/is-there-a-site-about-medicine-healthcare-and-illness#comment785581_239753) :

> There is a proposal on [Health](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66048/health) at Area 51

You can join that site proposal in the hopes it makes it to the [Beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) phase.

Comment: I'm just in illness. I'm very glad to seeing this agglomeration around stackoverflow, like stackexchange's Beer, Unix, Chess, etc. And I'm wondering why there is no Health?

Answer (score 2):

It's probably worth noting that Health Stack Exchange, from the proposal mentioned in [@CRABOLO's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239766/295232) has been [renamed to Medical Sciences Stack Exchange](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/956/7205) and [its scope has been changed to focus more on 'professional' questions](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/907/7205):

> Medical Sciences is a site primarily directed at professionals in medical and allied health fields, students of those professions, related academics, and others with a sound understanding of medicine and healthcare-related sciences.

A question about the differences in treatment of flu between different countries is *probably* on-topic, but not all questions about medicine, healthcare and illness are, in particular not most of the questions which were asked when it was still called Health Stack Exchange (IIRC it used to close more than 50% of the questions).

Answer (score -1):

Glorfindel and CRABOLO are correct.  I actually did learn something different from school last semester for on the topic of pharmaceuticals and psychology.
A lot of Medicine and Health Professors at Emory promote the bioinformatics stack exchange in addition to stack-overflow and cross-validated:
https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/109245/bioinformatics

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/71236)

Comment: @Rob This seems like a valid answer to me.

Comment: @Rob Its a valid answer.

Considering that Glorfindel and CRABOLO both mention 1) an Area 51 stackexchange and 2) mentioned how it covers part of the op question.

1) How does this require clarification from the asker? (There also have be no suggests or questions about my answer to guide me on what you even mean)
2) Why do you assume that there is a single stack exchange especially in Area 51?  As far as a question can have more than one answer.

Comment: Pierround, the comment (as it [mentions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/71236), is from the Review Queue and) is **automatically generated**. Because you are a new user we are happy to explain this to you. Someone else flagged your answer as "very low quality" (without explanation); presumably the reason is that you have used most of your answer to comment on other answers and suggested a site that isn't particularly [on-topic](https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35/4179) for the question being asked; and offer no reason. I am in agreement with 2 others.