# Requesting Expansion Regarding Old Answers

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, profile-page, users

A user answered a question relevant to something I'm working on myself, albeit back in the dark ages of 2011. I don't have enough reputation to post a comment for an incredibly minor clarification, I can't directly message users on here, and adding another 'answer' to the question, while my only real option, is quite the no-no.

Advice?

Comment: I recommend reviewing http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173 and working towards achieving a rep of 50 so that you can comment anywhere.

Comment: I wouldn't mind being able to do that, but most of what I do with SO is while I'm working. To take the time to scour multiple posts, looking for something I can answer, or simply skulking about for minor, ultimately insignificant edits for the sake of getting to that 50 rep seems a mix of counter-productivity and...well, prohibitively time consuming. Does that just mean I'm pretty much out of luck when it comes to raising my rep quickly-but-casually?

Comment: While your tact may have rankled me a bit initially, you present a good point. It has less to do with expecting handouts with nothing to offer in return, but more to do with self-confidence. I'm actually quite certain I have little experience or knowledge to offer that a thousand others around here don't already have, and better. If I would find an opportunity to contribute, I'd be absolutely psyched to. Realistically, though, I just don't feel I have the experience or knowledge to do so...yet!

Comment: Annnnd that prior comment was removed, completely eliminating any context for my own. Some of the conversations around here feel like Three Card Monte sometimes...

Comment: @Eiketsu - I removed it because I felt my comment was phrased too negatively.

Comment: It was, a bit. But like I said, it was an honest observation, and I'm doing my best to kind of clear up that I'm much more ignorant than lazy, so it wasn't doing any harm! :D

Answer (score 9):

Post a new question.

Yes, it may be "incredibly minor" - but perhaps you're not the only one to wonder about such a minor thing. If you ask, then *someone* can answer even if the author of that question is long gone, and that answer can benefit not just you but anyone else harboring the same doubt.

Explain your point of confusion, referencing the answer which sparked it. [Be detailed and specific](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Let the system work...

Answer (score 3):

Asking for "expansion" of an answer usually leads towards help vampirism in that the answerer is usually barraged until providing essentially a *second* answer to their already fully formed answer. Most people will disregard these comments.

If it is minor, does it really need clarification? It seems to me (and this is just assumption since the post wasn't linked) that a simple clarification could be determined on your own.

If it is not simple, these types of comments usually lead to enough response that they could have been their own questions. So this is really your best bet. If your situation is truly different then ask a unique question.

Comment: Alright, here's one more thing I'm wondering. That all seems like relatively good advice. Why would someone downvote you, and why aren't they encouraged to explain such decisions in the interest of improving things for everyone? Teach a man to fish, and all that...

Comment: No matter how minor, I would discourage anyone from earning the reputation to comment purely in the hope of finding clarification from an author who may or may not still be around and may or may not be interested in addressing comments on 3-year-old answers. If an answer raises a question, then the appropriate response is to research that question, and - if an answer cannot be found - ask it. This then goes on to benefit everyone.

Comment: The user's last login was two days ago, and he *does* stay active. I made sure to look into at least that much before looking for help with this, but...it really doesn't do me much good, either way. I've since been working on sorting this out on my own, but I'm not entirely certain I'm even applying the provided answer correctly. I could be wandering in the complete wrong direction.

Comment: @Shoggingthroughthesnow - Not sure how that differs from the answer I gave here though. I did not state that the reputation gain was "purely in the hope of finding a clarification" from the exact specific author but that having the 50 reputation would "already have saved that time at the very least". Placing privileges or goals in the gamification of SE (such as 50 rep earns comments) directly gives incentive for users to earn those privileges solely for their purpose. Since simple comments of "I agree" are usually not that purpose, they are probably mostly used for clarification.

Comment: Asking for clarification and expecting it are quite different, @TravisJ. As a business decision, earning the privilege to ask questions in the wrong place is not a very good one.

Comment: @Shoggingthroughthesnow - Yes, asking and expecting are different and as stated most people will disregard comments which are more than simple clarification. However, perhaps the comment was in the right place. "If the clarification is truly minor", I prefix my point with, which is to say perhaps it was on topic to the post and would get a response. Are clarifications merely questions in the wrong place? Perhaps the tooltip shouldn't read "Use comments to ask for clarifications" then.

Comment: Again, asking for a clarification and *treating the comment privilege as a business investment* are two quite different things, and it is the latter that you're suggesting here and which I object to. By all means, earn the privilege to post comments if you wish to help folks improve their posts by noting when they're unclear - but if you have a question *caused by* a lack of clarity, even a minor one, then pinning your hope on an author who for all you know may have no interest in helping you is a little bit naive; the whole system is designed around the idea of parallelism.

Comment: @Shoggingthroughthesnow - Since you seem so adamant about it I removed that part of my answer.

Answer (score -2):

If answer author is open to be contacted directly, you might found their contact option on their profile-page. Also it might not be so difficult to gaing enough reputatio to be able to post a comment.

Despite of the above, being an old answer it's probably that the author have moved into other projects and also is possible that the profile page be obsole so your best bet is that instead of making an "expansion request" is that you **make a new question**.

As was suggested in the [Shog9's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/246305/289691), "be detailed and specific", in other words, show what you have tried, share what you found, in this case the answer that you are referring and why it didn't meet your needs.

While you might be a member of the respective site for long time, review the help article about How to Ask a Good Question `/help/how-to-ask` as it might was improved since the last time that you had read it.