# Catch-22, recommendation of comment to user with low rep

Tags: discussion, comments, review, new-users

I have seen several comments to new participants that say:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.

When the new participant doesn't have 50 points yet, and isn't even close, this response doesn't seem helpful.

How can we deal with the problem more constructively?  Should we close the dud answer, encourage the new user to delete the answer, encourage editing the answer, explain for the future the difference between an Answer and a Comment, or some combination of the above?

For example, perhaps something like this:

> This sounds like more of a 'Comment' than an 'Answer', just to let you know.  You aren't allowed to submit 'Comments' until you have a reputation of at least 50, though; however, editing the post to improve it IS an option available to you already -- just click on the gray "Edit" link under your post.  If you haven't already taken the Tour (link), please take a look -- it will clarify further for you how the unique Stack Exchange Question and Answer system works.

Comment: I think telling them to edit would just confuse them more. Chances are very high that they *don't have* an answer so any edit they make will not improve it. And then they are in the awkward situation of "but I edited it like you said I should" and you end up having to basically post the same comment without the edit part.

Comment: @animuson - Good point.  Maybe it would help if we could figure out what our *goal* is in making a comment to a dud first attempt at an Answer.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Could you write an answer based on the other thread you found, please?  I'm not getting it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Thanks for that!  I thought there was something I was just not seeing.

Comment: Ask them to please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's fine as is.

Going through the current auto generated comment:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post

This first part tells them their answer is essentially not very good and should have been a comment. And even if you come up with an amazing alternative message, you will still need to tell them what exactly is wrong, and this already does that perfectly well.

> you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

This second part caters for users who don't have enough rep to comment. And this part has two links to the help center, one going to the reputation information page, and the other going to the comment everywhere page.

### What more can we do?

We currently tell them:

- Answer is poor
- Answer should have been a comment
- Links to help and info on rep and comments

What more can we do to help them? What more info could they need? The help center links are pretty informative.

### Your alternative example message

Provides no extra info to what is already there, even if that info is behind a link. In fact their being linked to the help center to get the info is arguably better as there is *more* info there, and they might wander around the help center a bit more.

Advising they can edit is largely pointless for this scenario as nearly always their answer *should* have been a comment and they're answering because they don't have 50 rep.

I think linking to the tour page is a fair idea, but it might be information overload, and we want to get a key message across. 
Simplicity is key here I think, especially as most cases user doesn't care as they are just frustrated they cannot comment.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution.  It has helped me realize I need to post a different question, posing the query that came up in my comment to @animuson.