# Why was a convert-answer-to-comment request turned down (at cost of -2 rep point for me)?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, convert-to-comment

I am just wondering. I have a quite specialization in some context. After I give the answer, sometimes the asker have made it through, but it seems to take a little closer step.

While I didn't have enough reputation points to make a comment.
So I write down an alternative answer again, but it is not that big an issue. It's, like, just added information, and the asker somehow can convert it as comment. That's awesome.

So in another case which is not quite different, I did like the one before, and I put some note to convert my answer as comment, you know.

And somehow, someone said "We don't convert answer as comment. Make sure that I should post answer. And if I didn't have enough reputation points to comment, I should wait until I have it".

It seems confusing and a little disappointing. You know how it felt, when we hoped that we can help someone, moreover we knew or have enough knowledge about the issue.

So how could someone convert an answer to a comment legally?
It's good though. And it will be useful as long as the converted answer is related to the topic and can be something to consider, not only for the asker, but to someone else as more clues.

It's okay to vote down or flag, or something else if it were pointless according to the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answers can be converted to comments manually by moderators only.

As a moderator, I occasionally exercise this option, but I will only do so if I think there appears to be particularly valuable content in the "answer" that is worthy of being temporarily available as a comment.

If the area reserved for direct answers to the question appears to have been used to try and make a comment instead, then I will on almost all occasions simply say that, and then delete it.

To do otherwise would turn the answer area into a quasi-comment box, and create much additional work for moderators.

We need new users to both learn the difference between content suitable for  answers and comments, and to [strive to achieve the comment everywhere privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead), as quickly as possible after joining a site.

Comment: Some trivial answers (according to a weird little algorithm that mostly checks to see if it's short and has a link) can also be auto-converted to comments without going through any intermediate answer stage.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Now that you mention it, I think I have seen that but not often, and wondered what had happened.

Comment: @PolyGeo I'm a newbie joined in this site, before that I only use the site to find answer related to my issue, but, it will be more exciting if I can contribute to, so I join. Your post makes my mind more wide open, but, unfortunately, my issue that makes me post this Question being deleted. Can't track any in my inbox. And I realize, that I lost my rep too. 11, become 9 because of the '-2', and now become only 1. Which makes me more confused and feel I'm just a dumb. I tough that only pros can contribute, not the learner.

Comment: @PolyGeo your post quite usefull by the way :)

Answer (score 6):

You should always be able to comment on your own answer. Also, you can edit your answer. So in the case you describe, the right thing to do is never to add another answer and hope someone turns it into a comment. Work with the answer you have.

The -2 was because someone downvoted your answer. If you delete it, the rep will come back.