# Didn't have enough rep but can make comment? How is that possible? Is it bug or?

Tags: support, reputation, comments, privileges

just wondering, I only have 46 rep point currently in askubuntu.
So we can said that I didn't have previlege to post a comment, right?

But, just about an hour ago, I tried to make comment in my answer, because the asker seems, a little bit close to make it through. So according to my experience before that cause me -2 rep point (see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269090/why-somebody-else-said-they-dont-convert-answer-as-comment-its-causing-2-rep) for my explaination),  I insist to make a comment. And I did successfully.
See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692770/lubuntu-15-04-wifi-not-working/692799?noredirect=1#comment1016701_692799) for my case.

Why is that possible?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I didn't read the FAQ's carefully. I can make a comment to my own post. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do comments work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

Comment: How is this different from your other question?, *[Why was convert answer to comment request turned down (at cost of -2 rep point for me)?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269090)*

Answer (score 5):

You can always comment on your own posts and answers to your questions.

Comment: Yes, I just notice that and already told it in comment below my question. My bad :) Thank's by the way.

Comment: @adadion: Comments are meant to be transient, if you are answering your own question, you should rather post an answer instead of a comment. It is okay to answer your own question.

Comment: you already do that for me ;)

Comment: Yeah, I meant for the next time. :)