# Add link to the "50 rep to comment" FAQ to the VLQ auto-response

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, review, low-quality-posts

I'm seeing quite a lot of low-rep people posting comments as answers and, upon receiving the corresponding VLQ reply:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or
>   request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post
>   - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient
>   [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

they respond that they know this and are posting an answer solely because they don't have rep to post comments - or they definitely would.

[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) has exactly the instructions on what they're supposed to do, but they never see it, and the links in the message aren't of much help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting today, for authors with less than the necessary reputation to comment [who are *not* self-answering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274530/canned-review-comments-should-factor-in-answers-owned-by-asker), the text of that comment will read,

> This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).