# Should all users be able to comment?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments

To comment, one must have at least 50 rep. In [Islam SE](https://islam.stackexchange.com/), users who are new have good information which would be best suited as a comment but they do not have 50 rep and therefore comment on the question in the answer.

Should all users be able to comment?

Answer (score 5):

#### Disagree.

As [quoted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174/350567),

> However, history and experience have shown that **the downsides** of allowing *everyone* to comment **are far greater than a few useful comments lost**:
>
> - There are big problems with **spam**. Automated filters cannot catch all of it.
> - Even among the real comments, most would either say "I have the same problem" or "I agree". Such comments **do not add any value**, and have to be manually removed.
> - Comments are very painful to moderate. Stack Exchange sites have a process of community moderation (voting, flagging, review queues) that works great for questions and answers, but not so much for comments. Comments cannot be downvoted or closevoted, nor searched (nor do we want that).
> - Comments are second class citizens on the Stack Exchange network, not designed to hold information for all eternity. They may get cleaned up at any time. Generally, **truly important information should be incorporated into an answer of its own anyway**.

So the Stack Exchange community decided to deny commenting everywhere for new users, because the cons are outweighing the pros.