# Add to help/privileges/comment link explaining why comments need higher reputation than answers

Tags: feature-request, reputation, comments, help-center

The question “Why do I need 50 reputation to comment?”  was raised many times (see duplicates of  [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) ).

It will be useful on [Comment Everywhere Privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) page ( and corresponding pages on other sites) add a reference to [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead), e.g.

> However, commenting on other people's posts is a privilege gained
>   from earning reputation (*The reason why is [described here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)*).If you
>   haven't earned it yet, try to get comfortable writing answers first.