# Rephrase low-quality-posts comment about “reputation required to comment”

Tags: feature-request, reputation, comments, review, low-quality-posts

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts has an option to select a comment:

> This is commentary on another post, not an answer.
>   “This does not
>   provide an answer to the question. Once you have
>   sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post;
>   instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the
>   asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).”

The last phrase assumes, that the user wants to gain reputation by answering any posts. However, quite often people are interested in commenting about particular answer/question, and "instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker" is irrelevant and confusing to them.

It will be better to clearly describe the link, e.g.

> This is commentary on another post, not an answer.   “This does not
>   provide an answer to the question. Once you have
>   sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post. *See 
>   [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) FAQ*