# How can I help correct an answer if I don't have enough reputation to comment?

Tags: support, reputation, comments

[This Code Review question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/177962/find-the-most-common-number-in-an-array-of-numbers?newreg=fdf4ad8a2818465a8f62c89abc8bb0f1) has an accepted answer with a single issue that I wanted to help note/fix.

> Then Blindman67 suggested the naive approach with this solution:
>
> ```
> function findCommon(arr)..."
> ```
>
> This implementation has a small error when given an array with a single high value (e.g. arr = [1,2,33,2,1,1] it returns 2 as the most common number).

How can a user that has a low reputation reach out to a user/community to help correct this answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can post an answer with an alternate solution. Just make sure that it's a solution to the problem, and not just an effective comment on the answer.

For example,

> Blindman67's answer that does [x] is good. However, their implementation has a small error when given an array with a single high value (e.g. `arr = [1,2,33,2,1,1]` returns 2 as the most common number).
>
> Here's an alternate implementation with the error fixed:
>
> [insert code here]

From the FAQ [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead):

> If you saw something wrong with an existing answer, do mention it and its flaws [in a new answer], but **make sure you provide an alternative solution** that can stand on its own. Do not just copy and paste your original comment into the "answer" field.

Comment: In this scenario, I wasn't looking to add an additional solution, as their work is included in the larger (accepted) answer that is thorough and well-written. The FAQ was very clear in the options a low-rep user has, so I have accepted this as an answer. I understand why the barrier exists, however, I feel that there could be additional recourse for users to work within.