# How can I get someone knowledgeable to review my rejected edit?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

Yesterday I made a small but important [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22798102) to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44632770/11390778). But when I came back today to check that my edit had been reviewed and accepted, I noticed that my edit had been approved by three reviewers, but then rolled back by the author of the answer.

I tried to find a way to message the answer's author, [thewaywewere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4907913/thewaywewere), directly, but after searching meta I found that unless the author has their contact details on their profile page, there is no way for a new user to contact them (as user's need 50 reputation to comment on an answer).

I then tried to resubmit my edit, but it was rejected for nonsensical reasons by two reviewers, who had clearly not read the link I provided in my edit comment.

I then considered flagging thewaywewere's answer for moderator attention, but after creating an account to do this, I found out that this is also not an option for new users (as user's need 15 reputation to flag an answer).

I didn't want to write this question (as it doesn't have an answer that will be useful to future users of this site), but I was left with no other options (as I don't have time to repeatedly submit the same edit until the author accepts it). And so if someone here with more reputation than me could make the change I was trying to make, I'd appreciate it.

And in case someone were to read through my edit and still think that the answer by [thewaywewere](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4907913/thewaywewere) is correct, that is, you think that using --oem 3 (the default OCR engine mode) together with tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789, still works in tesseract-4.0.0a (which by default uses the LSTM OCR engine), then please read through these three links on the topic[[1]](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Planning#features-from-30x-which-are-missing-for-lstm)[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49030935/11390778)[[3]](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/751).

UPDATE: It seems the answer to my question is "as a new user you can't" and that I should either write my own answer (which would have one variable changed from a 3 to a 0) or 'move on' leaving an incorrect answer as the accepted and top answer to the question.

Comment: If the author has rejected your edit, move on.  You've done what you can.  If you believe it's wrong, downvote.

Comment: Edits are not meant to change the intent of a post. You should only edit grammar, presentation, spelling, etc., but not the central statements and codes. If you think that an answer is factilually wrong, feel free to downvote, write a new (correct) answer or leave a comment (if you have enough rep).

Comment: fbueckert I considered moving on, but then the answer would then be left to mislead users in the future and so I chose not to. If you don't have time to make the change I understand, but I was hopeful that someone here would be able to understand the mistake and fix it.

Comment: BDL I'm not changing the intent of the post. It has one small but important error which needs to be corrected, that is all. The author would realise his mistake if only I could contact him.

Comment: The owner has *already* rejected it.  That's your chance to make a change.  Afterwards, your only recourse is to downvote.  That's it.  Trying to slide in a sideways change by asking someone else to do it is...iffy, at best.

Comment: It's not iffy fbueckert, as unlike you I can't comment to explain the mistake to the author. If you don't have time to write a comment explaining his error, then move on.

Comment: Well, those are your options.  You're not allowed to put words in his mouth.  He saw it, he rejected it.  That's it, that's all.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but just letting you know, you can put an @ sign in front of a username to notify the user, e.g. @hunter2

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog Sorry Sonic, I'll take your word for it, but as you marked my post as a possible duplicate, I just assumed that it was you downvoted me (which would be fair enough if you thought my post was a duplicate).

Comment: Worth mentioning that it's merely a *possible* duplicate at this point; it hasn't yet been actually marked as a duplicate (four others need to agree). Also, note that here on Meta Stack Exchange, we mark questions as duplicates of questions tagged [tag:faq] if the answer to that question also addresses this question. The purpose of that is to point people to the canonical help. See [this section of our FAQ on how Meta Stack Exchange works](/a/47635/377214) and the last section of [our FAQ on duplicate closures](/a/10844/377214).

Comment: @fbueckert No they aren't my only  options. I'm allowed to discuss my edit with other users that are knowledgeable about the subject (and have enough reputation to leave a comment).

Comment: And, no matter what, the owner is given great leeway on their posts.  Even *if* someone else changes their post, they can always roll it back again.  You've made your case, it was rejected.  That happens.  If you feel that strongly about the answer being wrong, write your own.  If you feel the change is too minor to warrant a new answer...then is the edit really required in the first place?

Comment: @fbueckert I don't think the author is unreasonable and I'm sure that if someone commented with the first link in my post which says "These features still work with the old OCR engine (--oem 0), but are missing and desired for LSTM:  Black list / White list (See issue)" that he would make the change from --oem 3 to --oem 0. I don't agree that my only option left is to downvote him.

Comment: They saw your edit.  I don't doubt they also saw your edit comment.  I think it's perfectly reasonable for them to decide they didn't want the edit.  He overrode the acceptance and rejected it.  After that, you need to respect the author's wishes.

Comment: @fbueckert Yes the edit is required. He needs to change the OCR Engine mode from 3 to 0 as otherwise whitelisting doesn't work in Tesseract 4.0.0a. But that doesn't mean that his entire answer deserves to be downvoted, as everything else he has said is correct.

Comment: @fbueckert You think it's reasonable? Are you serious? Did you not read the links I gave in my post? Whitelisting does not work at all if you use OCR engine mode 3!

Comment: @hunter2: People have the right to be wrong, and to defend their wrongness. That's why we allow multiple answers; if it's wrong, and the OP refuses to correct it, you can provide a right answer.

Comment: @Sonic Well my post is downvoted to -5 and marked as a duplicate now (when clearly it's not). I'd already read through the links you provided, and none of them were of any help to a new user, as I can't comment, flag, and writing a new answer should not be considered acceptable in this situation. I posted here in the hope that a helpful user with  more reputation, would come along and sort this out by contacting the author via a comment, or editing the answer if they agreed with my change. But it appears my hope was in vain.

Comment: @NicolBolas Unlike you and fbueckert, I don't think that the OP is unreasonable, I just think that he saw an edit by an anonymous user on his third most upvoted answer, assumed he was right without reading the link in the edit comment, and then reverted the edit. Whereas if someone with reputation on stackoverflow were to make the same edit or to write a comment, I'm sure that he would pay more attention and realise his mistake.

Comment: On this site, we deal with general situations as they apply to all sites, not with specific situations on specific sites. If you want specific action to be taken as a result of something that happened on a particular site, this isn't the correct place to ask for it; the proper place to ask for it is on the site's per-site meta, which you can access via the site switcher on the top right corner on the site in question.

Comment: You should also look at the following (new) link: [How can I help correct an answer if I don't have enough reputation to comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319475/how-can-i-help-correct-an-answer-if-i-dont-have-enough-reputation-to-comment)

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog Thanks sonic :). I somehow missed that there was a meta site for each individual stack exchange site! :/ I saw similar questions to mine on this site (one was along the lines of 'can I contest an edit') and so I assumed that this was the right place to ask.

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog One last thing. Is there a way for me to @ thewaywewere, so he can see this post? Or can I only notify users that have already commented in this thread? Because I'm sure that if he were to read through my post, and in particular this [link](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Planning#features-from-30x-which-are-missing-for-lstm), that he would see the error in his answer. It seems really awkward that my only option is to write an entirely new answer, which won't be the answer most people see when they visit the page.

Comment: Nope, it only works for people who were involved with this post (edited, commented, etc.)

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog Yeah that's what I thought. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You can make your case on Meta Stack Overflow (now that you know about it).  This is the meta site for all of Stack Exchange.  We aren't all programmers here, and not all programmers are versed in particular libraries/interfaces.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Thanks I realise that you aren't all programmers, but I was hoping that someone would actually answer the question I asked, which was: "How can I get someone knowledgeable to review my edit". But instead of answering my question they downvoted me without commenting and marked my question as a duplicate of "How do suggested edits work" and "how can I correct a reviewer's opinion" without reading it.

Comment: @MonicaCellio It's disappointing that when I go out of my way to try to make an important change to an accepted answer, for the benefit of future users of the site, all I get in return (other than a polite response from Sonic) is downvotes and rude responses from user's like fbueckert (who clearly didn't even read my post, as I explicitly said that I was a new user and couldn't contact the author via a comment).

Answer (score 6):

There's really no need for anyone to review the suggested edit; the post owner did so, and decided to reject it.  That is their right, as the post owner.  If you feel that the post is still incorrect, there are a few options you have available:

1. Write your own answer with the correct information.
2. Downvote the answer you attempted to change.
3. Comment on it to convince the author to change it.
4. Move on.

You can apply one or more of these actions.

Notice that continuing to attempt to edit the post is no longer in the list of options; that avenue has been exhausted.  We try to ensure that we preserve the author's intent, and that applies here.  They did not want the edit, ergo, the edit does not happen.  Asking someone else to apply it for you is a misuse of editing, and disrespects the original author.

Comment: I asked someone to review my edit and to either apply it if they agreed with the change I made (--oem 3 to --oem 0), or to leave a comment explaining the author's mistake, as I can't. That is not a misuse of the editing feature. This edit may seem minor to you, but it's actually very important, as if someone were to use his code, it could appear that whitelisting is working at first (as Tesseract's LSTM engine won't usually misidentify numbers as letters), only for it to fail later.

Comment: @hunter2 You had your chance.  It was rejected.  Asking someone else to do it for you *is* a misuse of editing.  Respect the author's intent, always.  If you think the answer is wrong, *write your own*.

Comment: @hunter2: You cannot *force* someone to accept a change to their answer. If they genuinely believe it is fine as is, then that's that. Just post a competing answer, one that also explains why that option is essential.

Comment: @NicolBolas I'm not trying to force him to do anything. If I'd contacted him and he had said "I know I'm wrong but I'm not changing my answer" then I would downvote him. But I'm not going  to do  that because I don't think  he  is unreasonable  and I'm sure that if someone were to leave a comment with a link to the official answer on the tesseract GitHub page, I'm sure that thewaywewere would correct his answer.

Comment: @hunter2 If you have enough rep to downvote, you have enough to comment.

Comment: @fbueckert I didn't downvote you. Check the rep on my account.

Comment: @hunter2 I didn't say you did.  I was responding to your comment about not downvoting the post author.  You're trying to convince him, and won't downvote him.  That implies you can, which means *you can leave a comment on his post*.

Comment: @fbueckert My mistake it was a hypothetical, and I hadn't actually checked  if I could downvote him.

Comment: @hunter2 Well, then you know what you can do.  This is going in circles, so I see no reason to continue.

Comment: @fbueckert No I'm hoping that someone helpful comes along that understands how to use Tesseract and can contact the author via a comment :).

Comment: @fbueckert You didn't actually answer my question. I asked "How can I get someone knowledgeable to review my edit", not "Is there a need for anyone to review my edit". Also it's not up to you to decide what is a misuse of the editing feature, if I was not allowed to make the same edit twice, then I'd be blocked from rolling back the last revision made, by the site. If you feel disrespected when someone corrects a mistake you made (e.g. by changing 1+1=3 to 1+1=2), then that is your problem not mine. Why you bothered to write a useless answer, is beyond me. You wanted internet points I suppose.

Comment: Welp, there goes all good faith interpretation, I see.  You are entitled to your opinion, no matter how wrong it is.  If you won't believe what everyone is telling you, then there's no point in continuing.