# No button to post a comment

Tags: bug, android-app

After opening any post that has no comments, I don't see any button to add comment. There is only button 'Add answer' below.

- App Version: 1.0.95

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Maybe because you do not have enough reputation to comment. It's [50](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: With *the usual comments* I assume you mean the chit-chat often found on traditional forums. You might want to go over the [tour] and the [help] to see what the Stack Exchange sites try to fix that is so broken in that forum model. But due to that awesome fix, we have a bit of a learning curve / set expectation levels here for new users, sorry about that.

Comment: Actually, it's not about _chit-chat_ or good old forums (whatever it means), I'm talking about feature to ask author to provide additional information, for example. It's basic and obivious feature and it's not too smart to restrict it, if you ask me.

Comment: Consider reading [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). Also, as an avid SE app user, I'd recommend to get familiar with the site on web version first because the app lacks guidance and help center.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason why you can’t add a comment is because you need 50 reputation to comment on most sites including Stack Overflow.

According to the [comment privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) you need 50 reputation to comment.

Anybody with 1 reputation can add an answer, though, according to the [Create Posts privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-posts) page. That is why you can see that button and not the comment button.

Answer (score 2):

You currently have only 25 reputation on Stack-overflow, when you need 50 to get comment privilege, see:

*https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges*

You haven't earned that yet so even on Computer you won't see it :-)