# How did this user post a comment on other's answer without 50 rep?

Tags: support, reputation, comments

An hour ago a new user (1 rep) posted [a comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/177904/disable-magnetic-screen-on-off-without-xposed/179944?noredirect=1#comment267947_179944) on my answer, where the question is asked by another user.

I don't know why this has happened because IMO that user needed 50 rep to post the comment.

None of the cases mentioned in the FAQ where a low-rep user can post a comment applies:

- Both the question and the answer aren't owned by the user
- The user is absolutely new and never had 50 rep
- It's not on Meta Stack Exchange
- The comment is on an answer

> [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48tDE.jpg) (too big to inline)

Comment: The FAQ [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) has a full section as to how it's possible for new users to post comments in certain cases.

Comment: @Sonic None of the ways mentioned in the FAQ applies.

Comment: It's possible for moderators to convert answers to comments and have the comment placed on another answer to the same question, not only on the question itself. Moderator conversions are indeed mentioned in the FAQ.

Comment: Well, *technically* it was covered by the FAQ, since it didn't explicitly mention that moderators can only convert answers into comments on questions (it just said generally that they can be converted to comments, without specifying on what). But as this has been answered by an employee and is linked as a source there, I've retracted my vote.

Comment: @Sonic answer converted to comment isn't the only option, e.g. I'm pretty sure 1 rep user with employee bit can do it either. Since we have no way to know for sure, it might also be a bug, and must be checked one case at a time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Moderators can convert answers to comments. That's what happened here.

[image: Deleted answer, converted to a comment]

While *usually* mods convert an answer to a comment on the question, it is possible to convert an answer to a comment on another answer on the same question. This is generally done when the new answer is an attempt to request clarification on the other answer.

The default for the convert to comment tool is for the question but a moderator can replace the question ID with an answer ID on the same question to put the comment there.

[image: Convert to Comment interface for moderators]

Comment: If a moderator converts an answer of a no-rep user to a comment, and the user gets a reply to that comment, is he able to reply back? (I.e. theoretically, I think that (similarly to the possibility of a user to comment his own answer) there should be a possibility for a user to to comment his comment-that-emerged-from-an-answer — but I don't know whether it's implemented in practice.)