# The problematic of inter-language migrating, the difficult of communication and my personal case

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, superuser, non-english-speakers, portuguese-stackoverflow

**My case**

I originally posted my question at Portuguese Stack Overflow (PT-SO), but it was closed because it was out of the programming scope.

The moderator advised me to post it on Super User and I did, but there my question was migrated to English Stack Overflow (EN-SO) because "it can be answered there."

- [Access/MySQL - Migração com retrocompatibilidade; Tabelas vinculadas [fechada]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/429989/access-mysql-migra%C3%A7%C3%A3o-com-retrocompatibilidade-tabelas-vinculadas)
- [Access/MySQL - Migration with backward compatibility; Linked tables [migrated]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59672145/access-mysql-migration-with-backward-compatibility-linked-tables)

<strike>**Communication**</strike>

There is no way to send personal messages, and I have no way to participate in discussions either in PT or EN Stack Overflow other than editing my post, because I don't have enough reputation to comment here.

Comments are important problem solving tools. At least, I can't find any other way to discuss what would happen to a question that's out of place. (?)

Thus, I don't agree with restricting access to this resource by reputation points. It's too important and shouldn't be blocked like that. Okay, it's not a huge number of reputation points that are needed, but I don't have enough, and I needed that feature.

**Inter-language migrating**

The solution I can think of to avoid cases like mine is to create a standardized way for authors of out of scope questions in non-English sites to migrate-and-be-translated to another site recommended by the user that closed the question. This way the questions will have a history, and someone will think again before migrating/closing it again.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: My thought is that I don't understand your exact question.

Comment: And you can always comment on your own questions

Comment: That mod on PT.SO made a bad call on suggesting another site. It happens.

Comment: We are all human, and humans make mistakes.  If something has gone horribly wrong with your question, and it landed in the wrong place, you can flag the question itself and ask for help.  Then check your flag history to read the response.  For example, you could ask for the issue to be discussed at the appropriate site Meta. // Do try to bring up your reputation with small things over time so that you have an easier time functioning.

Comment: Your "communication" issue is addressed in [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). Also, you *can* comment on your *own* posts without 50 reputation; if you aren't able to do so for some reason, it's an account problem, and you should follow the instructions there to fix it.

Comment: It still seems to be open on English SO so it is a bit hard to see what the problem is now.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few issues here — there are quite a few sites that could
be a good fit, and I don’t really know the norms of the sites other
than my own.

It’s *not* really a Super User question though — SU is meant for
personal-use-type things (broadly). That said, I can’t realistically
expect an SO (in lang) mod or user to have a perfect knowledge of
my site.

I’d have considered DBA as an alternative.

Non-English sites — well, are mostly SO, and since most of the rest
of the next of the network is English-speaking, finding someone who
speaks your language, and the language of your code is ... tricky.

Practically — it’s probably a good idea to double-check to see if
it’s on topic on your own, and such.

There are a lot of tricky things (translating — understanding and
preserving your intent) in this case, and I’m not really sure there’s
a great technical solution for this.

(As an aside, while I don’t read Portuguese, or code, that looks
like an MVCE comment, not a “try another site” comment from the mod.)

Comment: Where MVCE stands for Minimal, Verifiable, Complete, Example. Or in normal terms, and example that when we run it produces the same problem you currently face, and is as small as possible.

Comment: Yup but it's in Portuguese, which I do not read 

Comment: My google translate does ;), but this was more ment as info towards OP.\

Comment: Actually, the comment in SOpt says "*try SuperUser or another network sites, or edit the question adding a mcve (as long as it's a coding problem, not just an OS config issue)*". So it was actually suggested to post in other site...