# Where should I ask a question about an answer?

Tags: discussion, comments

I have a question about an answer given by somebody on a question. How do I tag that person and ask my question regarding his answer? This is in Cryptography Exchange.

Comment: Please don't use ALL CAPS in your question titles.

Comment: Partly it may solve my problem if the original problem solver clarified my doubt on his answer. However, I thought it will not be appropriate to post a doubt in an answer! This link enhances the solution and does not ask for clarification.

Comment: You could try to reach out to them in chat if you have enough reputation (20).

Answer (score 1):

To ask for a clarification of the content in a post (question or answer) you should use a comment on that post.

However, if that post is not yours then you will need the [comment everywhere](https://cryptography.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) privilege which comes at a reputation of 50 points on most sites.  On this site (Meta Stack Exchange) it comes at only [5 points.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)

If you have less than the required reputation to comment everywhere then see [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead/214174#214174)

Comment: I remember this being asked about before and me answering. Proposed a duplicate.