# Show the number of comments on the Top Questions page

Tags: feature-request, comments, homepage

Would it be possible to have, in the "Top Questions"/"Home" page, the number of comments next to the number of votes, answers and views?

Comment: Why? What benefit would that bring?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Comments are [second class citizens](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174/295232) on Stack Exchange, so they're less visible than questions and answers. The main problem is that (without reading them), the number of comments<sup>*</sup> conveys **absolutely nothing**. It could be that the question is rather unclear, and the comments are trying to clarify (but you don't know whether that was successful until you read them); it could be that there's a lot of discussion (in which case the comments aren't even used for [their intended purpose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)). Users may leave a (partial) answer in a comment, but again, that's not their purpose, and such comments should be converted into a proper answer.

Space is at a premium, especially often viewed pages like the question lists. So I don't think it is a good idea to add the number of comments to those pages.

<sub>*: under the question alone, or the entire Q&A thread? Anyway, it doesn't matter...</sub>

Comment: I just wanted to see if any new comments appeared without opening the question, so without falsely increasing the number of views.
But I understand your point of view.
Thank you

Comment: You can 'follow' questions you're interested in to get notified when a new comment is posted.