# What's considered "rude or abusive" on SE sites?

Tags: support, flags, offensive

I've seen a few SO/SE posts or answers that are mildly rude, abusive, or snarky (criticizing the post author's work, etc).  But I've never flagged any as rude or abusive simply because I don't know if I really should: how rude/abusive do you have to be for your question to be flagged? I looked at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging), but I still have the question of, "how rude do you have to be before your post is flagged"?

Comment: Note too that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) is a useful read about the subject too.

Comment: @RobertLongson but this question can be applied to all SE sites, right? So I shouldn't put it on SO meta.

Comment: That's not something that can be measured. There's no "rudeness meter". Any person who view a post and consider it offensive can flag it, considering they have the required reputation. Even "worse" (for your question), the same post exactly might be totally legit for some people, and extremely offensive for other people.

Comment: @BentheCoder I see you've edited the question to say it's for all sites. It's fine here now that you've done that but you might get more generic answers than for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Re *"Does this help?"* and *"How big is your video?"*: [Stack Overflow is not a forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36818/would-you-recommend-stackexchange-sites-vs-other-types-of-forum/36828#36828). You have [enough reputation points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/) to comment on questions.

Comment: Presumably [you](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20585541/ben-the-coder) got [question-banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/) in December 2022 and started answering questions to get out of the question ban. Has that something to do with it? E.g., did you delete the questions ([see deleted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/deleted-questions/current)) with the offending comments and [as a result](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416125/#comment895735_416125) got question-banned?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum Nope, the "rude/abusive" posts weren't in response to *my* questions, they were responses to other ones.