# Should I ask questions if I am on strike?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Recently, I've come upon a really interesting question and would like to see it answered. However, I have signed the strike letter which says

> Until this matter is resolved satisfactorily, **we will be pausing activities including, but not limited to**: [moderation tasks]

My question is: does the phrase **including, but not limited to** include asking questions?

Here's the thing: I can live without voting/flagging questions/answers, but I want my own questions to be answered. (Yes, I know, how selfish of me!) I haven't seen any strikers asking questions on my main site, and I'm not sure it's because very few people on my site are striking, or they have suspended all activity.

I have also noticed users have different interpretations of 'striking'; for example, some opt to still clean up their site's meta, since that is where the negotiation updates will be posted etc.

What is the community's take on this?

---

I've decided to at least wait a bit before asking my question, since asking questions still brings traffic to the sites.

Comment: This is a personal choice. I choose to fully support the moderator's goals,which are to convince SE Inc. to involve the community in its decision-making processes, as they are dependent on that community for their entire business. In support of that goal, my interpretation of the strike is that I'm not performing any actions on SE sites other than on the meta sites, which are involved in the discussions and updates of the strike. Others may have a different viewpoint. Do what your conscience tells you is right - no one can make that decision for you.

Comment: This question prompted me to update my bio here with my position on the strike. I've held the same position since it started, but I realized I forgot to make it clear.

Comment: A strike must hurt the "target" company to be effective. And hurt **a lot**. This is true for any strike. In the process the strikers may be hurt too. This is the cost of any strike (real workers lose salary, for example). So, IMO, suspending any type of activity is the most effective way to hurt SE Inc. I strive to do so, even if sometimes it "hurts" me to force myself not to answer some questions, or commenting on some issues or even asking questions myself. ...

Comment: The *goal* isn't punishment, it is change. And it isn't to *cause* hurt - its to shed light on how some decisions are hurting the community, and open the way towards healing those rifts.

Comment: If you're worried about bringing traffic to the sites best bet is to not post, view or login at all

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unlike this XKCD - I don't think there's really a purity scale for striking.

[image: XKCD comic: "Fields Arranged by Purity" - sociologists, psychologists, biologists, chemists, physicists, and ... mathematicians]
 <sub>[XKCD 435: Purity](https://xkcd.com/435/)</sub>

I've been doing both questions and answers - though *not* moderating, since it seems to be the best balance for *me*.

On the other hand - I think there's a few important points to be made.

We shouldn't be questioning if someone is *striking* enough, or making a fuss if someone's not far enough on the purity scale for you (cause it doesn't exist). There's a few sparks of infighting I've seen around meta - which I feel isn't really productive. Its my opinion that we *should* accept that there's different levels of comfort and things we're willing to do, and we each act according to that. I'm posting questions and answers because to me it benefits the *community* and hopefully gives us a "normal" situation when the current strike is concluded. It's counterproductive if we're at each other's throats, rather than focused on change.

Also, the goals of the strike are to get the company to respect the work and needs of the community. It *isn't* a denial of content (but I won't blame you if you don't want to post here), or to *hurt* the company. It is to cause *change* - both on the short term with current policies, and with longer term goals.

With *this* site - since I consider it something essential for community activism, *and* community support, I personally continue to post, answer and give feedback. I've answered a question or two on other posts. On the other hand - I can understand if someone choses to scale back or move to avoid supporting the company.

So - the additional "not limited to" very much depends on what you feel is appropriate, from "moderation" to "questions" to "posting" to "moving to another site" and "quitting the internet and becoming a hermit". There's folks who are *not* striking and supporting the strike as well.

I'd say, outside the sort of burn out, and loss of interest that the company's actions here and before have wrought, there's no *formal* stoppage of posting however that I'm aware of.

Comment: Great answer. I misread "hermit" and ended up having a "green" moment :D if it was an option, I'd have quit the internet to become Kermit :'(

Comment: ain't easy being green. Or Blue I guess

Answer (score 12):

> I have also noticed users have different interpretations of
> 'striking',

I think that says it all. These sites are mostly moderated by volunteers. Most people come here to get answers to their questions. If there is a problem that you really need a solution to, I think you should ask about it (without any feeling of guilt or judgement). All the moderation tasks (whether done by a moderator or other users) are voluntary and anyone is free to do (or not do) any of them. There isn't supposed to be any judgement here for asking questions but not performing any moderation (for whatever reason; why you choose to do moderation or not is nobody's business except yours).

So yes, feel free to ask your question. You do not need anybody's permission for it.

Comment: To clarify, none of the [se] sites are *forums*. Forums are social networking sites. SE sites are question and answer sites, which is totally different, and SE sites should not be confused with or referred to as *forums*.

Comment: Oops - missed something else. These are not *volunteer run* sites. If they were run by the volunteers (community), there would be no strike, because the community had decided by consensus that ChatGPT should be banned. The issue is that the community was overruled by SE Inc. behind the community's back, in a way that can clearly be considered inappropriate. If the sites were *volunteer run*, SE Inc. could not have done what they did, and the strike never would have been necessary.

Comment: @KenWhite My answer isn't about discussing semantics. Call it forum, call it social media, call it Q and A, whatever, doesn't take anything away from the main point of what I am trying to say. Also, volunteer run doesn't mean I (or most of the people reading this question let's face it) think that this site is actually run by volunteers and that we don't know there's a big company behind it. This answer is not about merits of the strike nor company overruling the community.  It's about the OP's question of if he can post a question, and the answer is "yes" ...

Comment: ...regardless of OP being on strike or not. Also, everything the striking users don't want to do (moderate for instance) is voluntary, so answer would be same regardless of if they are or aren't on strike.

Comment: Semantics matter, so that people who read your answer do not get misinformation about what SE sites are or how they are operated. I did not voice an opinion about the merits of your answer, nor did I downvote it to voice disagreement. But it's important that people who read your answer get valid information, not disinformation, about the SE network of sites. Saying *forum* and *volunteer run* are both false, as neither of them is the case.

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you for pointing it out in the comment, but I think the post is fine as it is, and not disinformative

Comment: Suit yourself. It affects your future credibility, not mine. It would take almost no effort to edit your post to correct the false information it contains. The fact that you won't do so to be factual is quite surprising.

Comment: @KenWhite theres no disinformarion here and i am going to keep referring to it as a forum as I need. You are welcome to come and correct in the comments whenever you want

Comment: **IT IS NOT A FORUM**. That's an outright mischaracterization of the entire SE network. **NONE** of the SE sites are forums - they are ALL question and answer sites. Calling them forums gives new users the wrong impression of how the sites function, which leads to their misusing the sites. You are doing them harm, because misuse of the sites causes downvotes and question closures, which causes them to not want to stay here. If you can't be accurate, at least stop lyiing to them.

Comment: @user13267 you can refer to this as forum to yourself, in private, or in external sites. While you're here on Stack Exchange platform, use the true and correct word.

Comment: @Shadow you can call SE whatever high tech name you want, it's just a fancy forum as far as I'm concerned and I will refer to it as such whenever I feel comfortable or appropriate to do so. You are welcome to chime in with a correction in the comment if you want

Comment: @user13267 I can't care less. But as a moderator already said, you're acting against the site's Code of Conduct by telling misinformation on purpose, and at some point the mods will have to stop you if you keep doing it.

Comment: @Shadow you cared enough to comment it seems. Posting "misinformation" is against the code of conduct. This is not misinformation. SE is a forum whether you like it or not and calling it such is not misinformation, and if you think so I am allowed to disagree. If you don't want to, don't call it a forum. I think it is just a fancy forum and will call it what it is. As I said already, if you disagree you are always welcome to chime in with a helpful correction in the comments

Comment: Or correct the post itself. That's what the edit button is there for, like someone seems to have done already. I don't create a fuss if others edit to improve my posts as long as it doesn't take away from main message. You are welcome to take that avenue in the future as well.

Comment: Look, someone is using the [dictionary definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/forum) of "forum", in which case Stack Exchange is unequivocally a forum, and someone is using a kind of Stack-Exchange lingo definition (Stack Exchange was set up to overcome limitations of Internet forums commonly seen 15 years ago).  Pro-tip: nobody cares, move on.

Comment: Related: [Stack Overflow is not a forum](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36818/would-you-recommend-stackexchange-sites-vs-other-types-of-forum/36828#36828)

Comment: It is more than what it is called. This has very practical implications when users think they are on a forum and misuse the site by adding extra information or follow-ups by [posting answers as something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76653102/how-to-make-crud-operation-in-django-without-a-page-reload/76655666#76655666) (e.g., follow-ups to answers (even when having [enough reputation points to comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/) on said answers)).

Comment: @this or, the more logical explanation, they are new and just haven't understood all the features of the SE forum, like where/what the comment box is and what it is for

Answer (score 8):

> My question is: does the phrase including, but not limited to include asking questions?

That depends on what *you* believe should fall under it.

The strike letter calls upon the users of the SE sites to cease all moderation activities, not a complete ban of the sites. The authors of the letter also give a list of moderation activities that should be stopped, but they made that list non-exhaustive in case they missed something. I do not believe it was their intention to include non-moderation activities like posting and answering questions in the list.

On the other hand, some people find the situation so serious that they, on their own initiative, stopped more activity on the site than what the strike letter called for. That is their decision and they are fully within their rights to make that decision.

To what extent you want to stop your interaction with the sites is completely up to you. And don't let you be influenced too much by the number of questions you see from people who openly support the strike. In my experience, the people on strike are to a large extent the content curators and those people often have fewer question left to ask. Their activity usually consists more of answering and curation than asking questions.